# Current project does not support file deployment into Sitecore instance

Tags: jss, nextjs, jss-rendering-sdk

I've created a sample nextjs app using jss cli, but when I try to deploy it using:

```
jss deploy app
```

it deploys items successfully, but not files and throws the message below:

> The current project does not support file deployment into the Sitecore
> instance. You should use an HTTP POST based integration for Experience
> Editor support. See SDK documentation for details.

The same happens when I try to deploy files only via:

```
jss deploy files
```

But this works for react app, I'm experiencing this mentioned issue for nextjs app only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this point it is possible to use this approach below for nextjs app if it is needed to use Sitecore capabilities:

```
jss start:connected
```

After that, you can open the home page in Experience Editor, etc.